# Pandas: Get Dummies

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have the following dataframe:

```
   amount  catcode    cid      cycle      date     di  feccandid    type
0   1000    E1600   N00029285   2014    2014-05-15  D   H8TX22107   24K
1   5000    G4600   N00026722   2014    2013-10-22  D   H4TX28046   24K
2      4    C2100   N00030676   2014    2014-03-26  D   H0MO07113   24Z
```

I want to make dummy variables for the values in column `type`. There about 15. I have tried this:

`pd.get_dummies(df['type'])`

And it returns this:

```
           24A  24C  24E  24F  24K  24N  24P  24R  24Z
date                                    
2014-05-15  0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
2013-10-22  0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
2014-03-26  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

What I would like is to have a dummy variable column for each unique value in `Type`

Comment: don't you mean `pd.get_dummies(df['type'])`?

Comment: Yes! thank you. Now is there a way to add it do my df or should I just do a join?

Comment: What do you expect the final df to actually look like though?

Comment: The new fd should include the dummy columns in the new df

Comment: So you can just `join` then: `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['type']))`

Comment: It returns a memory error when I do the df.join.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can try :

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['type'])
```

Answer (score 32):

Consider I have the following dataframe:

```
   Survived  Pclass     Sex   Age     Fare
0         0       3    male  22.0   7.2500
1         1       1  female  38.0  71.2833
2         1       3  female  26.0   7.9250
3         1       1  female  35.0  53.1000
4         0       3    male  35.0   8.0500
```

There are two ways to implement get_dummies:

**Method 1:**

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns = ['Sex'])
```

This will return:

```
   Survived  Pclass  Age     Fare  Sex_female  Sex_male
0         0       3   22   7.2500           0         1
1         1       1   38  71.2833           1         0
2         1       3   26   7.9250           1         0
3         1       1   35  53.1000           1         0
4         0       3   35   8.0500           0         1
```

**Method 2:**

```
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(dataset['Sex'])
```

This will return:

```
   female  male
0       0     1
1       1     0
2       1     0
3       1     0
4       0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using preprocessing package

```
X=df.values()

from sklearn import preprocessing

le_type= preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

X[:,7]=le_type.fit_transform(X[:,7])
```

This fits and transforms the encoded values in the original dataset

Answer (score -1):

Another way is:

```py
pd.get_dummies(df.type)
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try :

```
type_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['type'],drop_first=True)  
df = pd.concat([df,type_dummies],axis=1)
```