# OneHotEncoder: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, reshape, one-hot-encoding

I want to one-hot encode the `sex` column in my dataframe `df`. I reshaped it using `reshape(-1, 1)` but still get an error `Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User/Downloads/suicide_rates.csv')

df['sex'] = ohe.fit_transform(df['sex']).toarray().reshape(-1, 1)
```

Traceback

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=['male'
> 'male' 'female' ... 'male' 'female' 'female']. Reshape your data
> either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or
> array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the parenthesis before actually reshaping the array.

The other problem is that the one hot encoder is creating several columns, you cannot assign that to a single column:

```py
In [1]: from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"sex": list("mmmfff")})

In [4]: ohe = OneHotEncoder()

In [5]: ohe.fit_transform(df["sex"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1))
Out[5]: 
<9x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [6]: _.toarray()
Out[6]: 
array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.]])
```

You see that we have 2 columns. If you are sure that you have only 2 values, you can use the `drop` parameter of `OneHotEncoder`, it will drop the first value, and you can assign that to the dataframe:

```py
In [11]: ohe_with_drop = OneHotEncoder(drop="first")

In [12]: ohe_with_drop.fit_transform(df["sex"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
Out[12]: 
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
In [13]: df["sex_ohe"] = ohe_with_drop.fit_transform(df["sex"].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
  sex  sex_ohe
0   m      1.0
1   m      1.0
2   m      1.0
3   f      0.0
4   f      0.0
5   f      0.0
```

See the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features) for more about one hot encoding.

As an alternative, you can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```py
In [18]: pd.get_dummies(df["sex"])
Out[18]: 
   f  m
0  0  1
1  0  1
2  0  1
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  1  0
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923927/pandas-sklearn-one-hot-encoding-dataframe-or-numpy) for more.

Comment: It raises `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

Comment: Ah, yes, I replied too fast. You cannot assign to a column, as the `OneHotEncode` will create several columns. I'll edit the answer